# Postgres-15.1 is restarting continuously on using shared_preload_libraries extension

Tags: postgresql, openssl, centos7, citus, postgresql-15

Postgres is restarting continuously on using shared_preload_libraries extension.
https://postgresqlco.nf/doc/en/param/shared_preload_libraries/

I am running postgres-15.1 using a python-based daemon in CentOS7-32bit arch. It is working fine if we do not use "shared_preload_libraries" extension. But after enabling this extension using "ALTER SYSTEM SET shared_preload_libraries" command, the postgres is restarting every few seconds.
Initially it was working fine with postgres-9.6.4.

Postgres logs:

```
waiting for server to start....2023-02-15 07:13:45.676 GMT [28605] LOG:  skipping missing configuration file "/home/runtime/pgsql/data/postgresql.auto.conf"
2023-02-15 07:13:45.825 GMT [28605] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.1 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44), 32-bit
2023-02-15 07:13:45.825 GMT [28605] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2023-02-15 07:13:45.933 GMT [28605] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/home/runtime/pgsql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-02-15 07:13:45.969 GMT [28608] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-02-15 07:13:35 GMT
2023-02-15 07:13:45.989 GMT [28605] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 done
server started

ALTER SYSTEM
ALTER SYSTEM
ALTER SYSTEM
ALTER SYSTEM
2023-02-15 07:13:51.480 GMT [28605] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
waiting for server to shut down....2023-02-15 07:13:51.512 GMT [28605] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2023-02-15 07:13:51.513 GMT [28605] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 28611) exited with exit code 1
2023-02-15 07:13:51.513 GMT [28606] LOG:  shutting down
2023-02-15 07:13:51.536 GMT [28606] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
2023-02-15 07:13:51.908 GMT [28606] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.090 s, sync=0.028 s, total=0.395 s; sync files=2, longest=0.021 s, average=0.014 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=0 kB
2023-02-15 07:13:51.909 GMT [28605] LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped
```

I tried to use postgres-15.0 and postgres-14.4, got the same behavior with both. I am not able to find any open issues w.r.t. `shared_preload_libraries` extension with new versions of Postgres.

PS: I have built this Postgres from the source code with openssl-1.1.1i.
I am using "citus" library with this.

> ALTER SYSTEM SET shared_preload_libraries="citus";

I have generated a new citus.so file from it's source code using postgres-15.1. github.com/citusdata/citus

```
waiting for server to start....2023-02-23 09:18:17.826 GMT [18659] LOG:  skipping missing configuration file "/home/runtime/pgsql/data/postgresql.auto.conf"
2023-02-23 09:18:18.102 GMT [18659] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.1 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44), 32-bit
2023-02-23 09:18:18.102 GMT [18659] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2023-02-23 09:18:18.183 GMT [18659] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/home/runtime/pgsql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-02-23 09:18:18.206 GMT [18662] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-02-23 09:18:07 GMT
2023-02-23 09:18:18.227 GMT [18659] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 done
server started
ALTER SYSTEM
ALTER SYSTEM
ALTER SYSTEM
ALTER SYSTEM
waiting for server to shut down....2023-02-23 09:18:23.510 GMT [18659] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2023-02-23 09:18:23.542 GMT [18659] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2023-02-23 09:18:23.543 GMT [18659] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 18665) exited with exit code 1
2023-02-23 09:18:23.543 GMT [18660] LOG:  shutting down
2023-02-23 09:18:23.587 GMT [18660] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
2023-02-23 09:18:23.787 GMT [18660] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.054 s, sync=0.047 s, total=0.244 s; sync files=2, longest=0.025 s, average=0.024 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=0 kB
2023-02-23 09:18:23.788 GMT [18659] LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped
waiting for server to start....2023-02-23 09:18:34.158 GMT [18824] LOG:  skipping missing configuration file "/home/runtime/pgsql/data/postgresql.auto.conf"
2023-02-23 09:18:34.228 GMT [18824] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.1 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44), 32-bit
2023-02-23 09:18:34.228 GMT [18824] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2023-02-23 09:18:34.297 GMT [18824] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/home/runtime/pgsql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-02-23 09:18:34.468 GMT [18827] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-02-23 09:18:23 GMT
2023-02-23 09:18:34.596 GMT [18824] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 done
server started
ALTER SYSTEM
ALTER SYSTEM
ALTER SYSTEM
ALTER SYSTEM
waiting for server to shut down....2023-02-23 09:18:40.156 GMT [18824] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2023-02-23 09:18:40.191 GMT [18824] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2023-02-23 09:18:40.192 GMT [18824] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 18830) exited with exit code 1
2023-02-23 09:18:40.192 GMT [18825] LOG:  shutting down
2023-02-23 09:18:40.238 GMT [18825] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
2023-02-23 09:18:40.513 GMT [18825] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.040 s, sync=0.003 s, total=0.322 s; sync files=2, longest=0.002 s, average=0.002 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=0 kB
2023-02-23 09:18:40.514 GMT [18824] LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped
waiting for server to start....2023-02-23 09:18:50.904 GMT [18986] LOG:  skipping missing configuration file "/home/runtime/pgsql/data/postgresql.auto.conf"
2023-02-23 09:18:51.032 GMT [18986] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.1 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44), 32-bit
2023-02-23 09:18:51.032 GMT [18986] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2023-02-23 09:18:51.140 GMT [18986] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/home/runtime/pgsql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-02-23 09:18:51.376 GMT [18989] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-02-23 09:18:40 GMT
2023-02-23 09:18:51.517 GMT [18986] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 done
server started
ALTER SYSTEM
ALTER SYSTEM
ALTER SYSTEM
ALTER SYSTEM
waiting for server to shut down....2023-02-23 09:18:57.194 GMT [18986] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2023-02-23 09:18:57.236 GMT [18986] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2023-02-23 09:18:57.237 GMT [18986] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 18993) exited with exit code 1
2023-02-23 09:18:57.237 GMT [18987] LOG:  shutting down
2023-02-23 09:18:57.550 GMT [18987] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
2023-02-23 09:18:57.783 GMT [18987] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.007 s, sync=0.024 s, total=0.546 s; sync files=2, longest=0.021 s, average=0.012 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=0 kB
2023-02-23 09:18:57.785 GMT [18986] LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped
```

Comment: Maybe some details of the shared library you are using might help others to help you?

Comment: You forgot to add the crucial piece of information: what did you put into `shared_preload_libraries`? Please [edit] the question, don't write it as a comment.

Comment: I am using "citus" library with this. ALTER SYSTEM SET shared_preload_libraries="citus"; I have generated a new citus.so file from it's source code using postgres-15.1. github.com/citusdata/citus

Comment: Which version of citus?

Comment: Using Citus-v11.2.0

Comment: Can you share logs on what happens when you try to start the database? Since as far as I can see from those logs, there only 1 shut down after running ALTER SYSTEM. I am curious to see the logs of the db restarting every few seconds.

Comment: Thanks for sharing more logs. What are those 4 `ALTER SYSTEM` commands that show in the logs after each restart attempt? Are you running them yourself?

Comment: It is also strange that you are missing `postgresql.auto.conf` and that file is required for `ALTER SYSTEM SET` to work. Can you check the existence of said file?

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisites:

- install pg and citus
- add pg binaries to path

The following set of commands runs without errors in my local:

```bash
mkdir testdb
initdb -D testdb -U postgres
pg_ctl -D testdb -o "-p 3333" start
psql -p 3333 -U postgres -c "ALTER SYSTEM SET shared_preload_libraries='citus';"
pg_ctl -D testdb -o "-p 3333" restart
psql -p 3333 -U postgres -c "CREATE EXTENSION citus;"
```

Here, I:

- create a db from scratch
- run `ALTER SYSTEM SET shared_preload_libraries='citus';` which you
  shared
- restart the db (required for the changes of `ALTER SYSTEM SET` to take place; alternatively run `SELECT pg_reload_conf();` in the db)
- create the citus extension.

and everything works great!

Can you share the error you see when you try to start the db?